# Plot of numerical Integral of product of matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, matlab-figure, numerical-integration

I would like to compute numerically an integral of a function that is a product of matrices like this ([1 1 1] is a row matrix with 3 entries, A(t) is a 3x3 matrix with each entry a function of t and P(t),S(t) is a column matrix with each entry a function of t)
[image]

I then tried to plot the integral of this function with

```
g=@(upper)integral(@(t)f(t),0,upper)
```

and

```
t=0:0.1:10;
plot(g(t),t)
```

but this doesnt seem to work. For example to let matlab accept t in A(t) and P(t) I had to have

```
syms t
```

but then it complains about this symbol in the integration.

Comment: If you're looking for numerical values, don't uses `syms`; a lot of functions don't like `syms`.  Secondly, I suspect the issue is that `integral` doesn't like vector-valued arguments without the `'ArrayVauled',true` parameter-name pair.

Comment: What do you mean by “plot integral?” Do you mean like plot the bounds and the area underneath on a MATLAB figure?